# Android RecyclerView Adapter: notifyItemInserted and notifyItemMoved at index 0 not working

Tags: android

I have a RecyclerView with a horizontal linear layout manager declared like this:

```
RecyclerView graph = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.graph);

RecyclerView.LayoutManager classManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
graph.setLayoutManager(classManager);
graph.addItemDecoration(new ComponentDecorator(this)); //Just sets a margin around each item
```

I have a method which inserts a placeholder view into the RecyclerView like this:

```
private void insertPlaceholder(int index) {
    int placeholderIndex = getIndexOfPlaceholder(); //returns index of existing placeholder, -1 if none

    //No need to do anything
    if(placeholderIndex == index)
        return;

    if(placeholderIndex == -1) {
        ClassGraphItem placeholder = new ClassGraphItem();
        placeholder.setType(ClassGraphItem.PLACEHOLDER);

        mItems.add(index, placeholder);
        Print.log("notify item inserted at index", index);
        notifyItemInserted(index);
    }
    else {
        ClassGraphItem placeholder = mItems.get(placeholderIndex);
        mItems.remove(placeholderIndex);
        mItems.add(index, placeholder);

        notifyItemMoved(placeholderIndex, index);
    }
}
```

The placeholder is just an invisible view which simulates a space opening between two existing views:

```
private class PlaceholderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public PlaceholderViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(mComponentWidth, 1);
        itemView.setLayoutParams(params);

        itemView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

When the inserted index is > 0, it works perfectly. However at index 0, either inserting a placeholder, or moving an existing placeholder to the 0 index does not work, specifically the RecyclerView doesn't animate to show the new item inserted at index 0. If I used `notifyDataSetChanged()` it does work. however that doesn't animate and isn't the effect I'm looking for. This seems like a bug to me, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't something else that was causing this issue.

I'm on the latest version of the recyclerview support library (24.2.1). Thanks!

Comment: It was a bug in 22.x but was fixed in 23.x. If you are using 24.2.1, you should definitely check your code.

Comment: And If still it doesn't work, file a bug on issue tracker.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on 25.0.0

Answer (score 21):

I removed `recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);` and now it works.  I have no idea why this would be related though.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give this a try and let you know how it goes. Thanks! Feel free to ping me if I forget to report my results.

Comment: You forgot to report your results @JMRboosties :p

Comment: It worked in my case. 
In my opinion setHasFixedSize tells the recyclerview not to change its size so removing or adding elements doesn't refresh the recyclerview.
notifyDataSetChanged instead force the recyclerview to completely redraw itself and so it works but without animations

Answer (score 0):

This may happen because of setting `recycler.setHasStableIds(true)` and then using item's position to assign the `getItemId` in the adapter.

This will just update that one position and other items won't be shifted as they have should.