# notifyItemInserted() not working as I was expecting

Tags: android

What I need to do is inserting item to the top of `RecyclerView`. I have adapter which persists `List` of my items and when I want to add to the top of `RecyclerView` I'm simply using this code:

```
mItems.add(0, item);
notifyItemInserted(0)
```

Unfortunately it's just reloading last item of `RecyclerView`. Of course when I change `notifyItemInserted` to `notifyDataSetChanged()` everything works fine. Why is `notifyItemInserted` not appropriate?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39683237/android-recyclerview-adapter-notifyiteminserted-and-notifyitemmoved-at-index-0

Comment: @ThirdMartian how did you solve this?

Comment: I thought ```notifyItemInserted(0)``` was not working at first and came across this question, but apparently it was because my recyclerview was invisible in this particular edge case. So if your app has alot of Recycler visiblity changes, make sure you check that first. :)

Answer (score 35):

Just remove `setHasFixedSize(true)` from your initialization of RecyclerView.

Comment: I don't have setHasFixedSize(true) one but still not working

Answer (score 1):

```
mItems.add(0, item);

if(mItems.size()==1){

   notifyDataSetChanged();
} else {

notifyItemInserted(position);

}
```