# Recyclerview notifyItemInserted not updating scrollbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to add items to my recyclerview and that my scrollbar is updated accordingly.

Here is my RecyclerView :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/clear_grey"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        />
```

After adding an element to my dataset, I am calling

```
recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemInserted(recyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
```

The problem is, the scrollbar is not updated : I have to touch the views for it to be updated.

I was using

```
recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The scrollbar is updated, but I can't use this solution. (I need to be able to select text from the views, which is impossible with notifyDataSetChanged.)

Any ideas on how to update the scrollbar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had set fixedSize to true :

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

And thanks to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40373122/2437227, 
I tried without it and it works.